# Laravel conflicting routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

My `routes.php` excerpt:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {

    Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController', [
        'except' => ['show']
    ]);

    Route::delete('posts/trash', [
        'as' => 'posts.trash.empty',
        'uses' => 'PostsController@emptyTrash'
    ]);

});
```

My `PostsController.php` excerpt:

```
/**
 * DELETE /admin/posts/{id}
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    // code
}

/**
 * DELETE /admin/posts/trash
 */
public function emptyTrash()
{
    // code
}
```

The problem is that Laravel confuses the 'trash' string in a `DELETE /admin/posts/trash` request as an `{id}` parameter. As a consequence, the `destroy()` method is called instead of `emptyTrash()`. Why and What can I do for this?

Comment: Try changing the order of your routes. Put `Route::delete('posts/trash...` before `Route::resource...`

Comment: Yes it works. But I want to know why and actually a better way to do it than just rely on ordering. Maybe a model binding or an {id} check to be an int? Make it a complete answer to accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, **order matters**. Laravel will search the routes for a match in the order you register them. As you figured out, Laravel will take `trash` as an id and therefore the URI matches the resource route. Since that route is registered *before* your additional one, it will use the resource route.

The simplest fix is to just change that order:

```
Route::delete('posts/trash', [
    'as' => 'posts.trash.empty',
    'uses' => 'PostsController@emptyTrash'
]);

Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController', [
    'except' => ['show']
]);
```

If you don't like that you can try to limit the parameter for your resource route to numbers only. Unfortunately you can't just add a `->where()` to the resource route like you could with others.

Instead you have to define a [global pattern](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters) for the route parameter. The route parameter `Route::resource` chooses is the resource name (in snake_case).

So this should work for you:

```
Route::pattern('posts', '[0-9]+');
```

Comment: Thats great, the order matters to in Laravel `5.4`.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your view, you should have a button or a link for actually deleting the post.  The view should look something like this:

```
@section('content')
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <b>{{ $post->post_name . ' (id:' . $post->post_id . ')' }}</b><br />
        <b> {{ link_to_route('overview', 'Go Back To Post List') }}   </b>
        <div class="pull-right">
            // FORM FOR DELETING POST
            {{ Form::open(array('route' => array('delete_post', $post->post_id))) }}
                {{ link_to_route('edit_post', 'Edit Post', array('id' => $post->post_id), array('class' => 'post_img_button_edit')) }}
                {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
                {{ Form::submit('Delete Post', array('class' => 'post_img_button_delete')) }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>

      <div class="pull-right">
            // FORM FOR EMPTYING TRASH
            {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'empty_trash')) }}
                {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
                {{ Form::submit('Empty Trash', array('class' => 'post_img_button_delete')) }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>

    </div>

/* Additional HTML code within view */
```

Your controller should be similar to this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $this->post->delete($id);
    return \Redirect::route('overview'); 
}

public function emptyTrash()
{
  // code for collecting and emptying Trash
}
```

And your routes should look similar to this:

```
Route::delete('admin_posts/admin_posts/{id}/destroy', array('as'=>'delete_post', 'uses'=>'PostsController@destroy'));

Route::delete('posts/trash', array('as'=>'empty_trash', 'uses'=>'PostsController@emptyTrash'));
```

The name of your route for actually *deleting posts* be **'delete_post'**.

The name of your route for *emptying your trash* will be **empty_trash**

Basically you're explicitly defining your routes so that you'll avoid less ambiguity and Laravel will know which routes to take.  Hopefully this information will help!

Comment: I already tried to change the route name and set my form like this: `{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => 'delete_post']) !!}` with no success.

Comment: @AntonisGr Ok, give me a few minutes.  I'll edit my answer above with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: thanks but this is not the problem. Please see the other answer. It s the routes order that is problematic!

Comment: @AntonisGr No problem.  The order of your routes is actually important as lukasgeiter mentioned.  I've just learned from using Laravel that you have to be explicit with how you define routes and how they're actually called by your controllers, etc.